# I Could not solved this NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, exception, viewdidload

Here is my code:

```
@interface TabRegsViewController ()
@end

@implementation TabRegsViewController

@synthesize parent;
@synthesize menu_select;

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {    
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"***************\t\t\tTab_Reg_ViewDidLoad");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //[super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"***************\t\t\tTab_Reg_ViewDidAppear");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This UI only makes the storyboard.

This storyboard plays in an iPhone 5, however my iPhone 6 Plus cannot.

> *************  tab_reg_ViewDidload
>
> terminating app to uncaught exception
>
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects: count: ]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

I don't know what to do.

After this parent class button event happens, `presentViewController` event occurs and the page changes.

iPhone 5 works but iPhone 6 plus fails.

I think this `TabRegsViewController` `viewDidLoad` is okay, but an exception.

I don't know how to clear this exception.

Please help me.

Edit :

This Class Call method, and this vc pointer and self is nil. why?..

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStroyboard storyboardWithName:"Main_Storyboard" bundle:nil];
TabRegsViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabRegsViewController"];
vc.parent = self;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and current exception point is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromclass([Appdelegate class]));
    }
}
```

error is Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
argc (int)
argv = (unsigned char ** )NULL

Comment: Which line of code is causes the exception? None of the code you posted is creating an array.

Comment: And why don't your `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear:` methods call `super`?

Comment: super methods not call reason nothing... only test;;;

Comment: i don't know line of code exception... this class is only this code... so i don't know what..

Comment: Look at the stack trace. If you don't know how to debug crashes, please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I Think that presentviewcontroller is call two.. <<problem...?

example I want to go to 3 but stroyboard 1->2->3.
so call presentViewcontroller:2 and 2 class init is presentViewController:3

this can make this bug??

Comment: I Think That Xcode program issue..? Because when I get App in Appstore, this issue is solved...;;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the nibNameOrNil is nil, add a breakpoint to the line below. And tell us what you get.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
     //Add a breakpoint overhere or NSLog the value nibNameOrNil and nibBundleOrnil
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
```

Follow up answer:
Okay, from reading those screenshot I can only have a rough idea of your structure. And the code looks fine. From my experience, this error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects: count: ]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

is usually happens when you calling some method but some parameter are missing.

You mentions

> This Class Call method, and this vc pointer and self is nil. why?..

you add a breakpoint at which position and find out that self is nil??
need more code for me to trace the error||

Comment: okay,, i just read your edited question. whats the point of the line "vc.parent = self;". I think you can remove that line.

Comment: if you don't mind, you can send me those vc files and i can help you to look into it.

Comment: vc.parent mean is vc(viewController).parent(pointer) = self(me) mean...
This TabRegsViewController.h have @property (readwrite) WaitingViewController *parent;
and WaitingViewController is parent View. if you from korea, plz give me your e-mail.. 
I Can Speak english very very a little...

Comment: pandaxbacon@icloud.com ... i am from hongkong.. i think your english is okay :D
it's hard to understand your problem only by text||

Comment: i Send the e_mail.. with jpeg file(capture..)

Comment: you missed From = 3; in the onInitViewController method?

Comment: and i Think nil.. nil.. is very important keyword.. but another device(iphone5, ipad2) is work.. why iphone6plus ..................................................................................................

Comment: viewDidLoad in TabRegsViewController.m is work.. but next kill app..;;
i don't know why storyboard viewController is not drawing;;;...